# Cannot extend CocoaPods class in my Swift class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, swift, cocoapods

I've tried following the tutorial at https://vimeo.com/107295686, and failed very early.

Basically, I've:

- created project
- created Podfile which requires [BDBOAuth1Manager](https://cocoapods.org/pods/BDBOAuth1Manager) and AFNetworking
- installed cocoapods, closed XCode, and reopened it in my MyProject.xcworkspace directory.
- Created and deleted a dummy Objective-C file, because I needed bridging header
- Added #include directive to this header, which asks for BDBOAuth[...].h
- Created Cocoa Touch class which extends BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class RESTClient: BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager {

}
```

And now I can't instantiate my new Cocoa Touch class.

When I try to call constructor, this is the hint I get 
[image: screenshot]

Note that method description says "Initializes an instance of the class that implements the video compositing protocol", which has nothing to do with my OAuth intentions. When I switch back to my class, and command-click the class I've tried to extend, I get the correct file with correct init params.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to do this exact thing (same library), I had to change the import statements in BDBOAuth1Manager to use

```
 #import <AFNetworking/xxx.h>.
```

My project wouldn't build without it. Have you checked the header search paths?

Comment: Actually, the thing that did the trick was - completely ignoring XCode's hints. I've typed all init parameters by hand (found them in BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h) and my project has compiled with no errors. Thanks for chiming in, though, I really appreciate it.